# found nil while trying to segue away from a tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, null, tableview

I'm getting errors whenever I try to reference the viewTable in the viewDidLoad AFTER I click on a cell to transition with the segue. Thanks a lot!!

Basically I can't use the segue unless I comment out the tableview references in view did load... but I need those in order to use the search bar and im sure it will cause problems on the way back...

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


        @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView! {
            didSet {
                print("tableView is set")
            }
        }
        let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        let textCellIdentifier = "TextCell"
        var buildings: [(String,String)] = []
        var filteredBuildings = [(String,String)]()
        var goToIndex: Int?

        override func viewDidLoad() {



            super.viewDidLoad()

            print(tableView)
            var buildingTuples = loadBuildings()

            for tuple in buildingTuples {
                self.buildings.append(tuple)
            }


            self.goToIndex = -1

            searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
            searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
            definesPresentationContext = true
            tableView!.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

        }


        func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
            filteredBuildings = buildings.filter { building in
                return building.0.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString)
            }

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

        // MARK:  UITextFieldDelegate Methods
        func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            //return self.buildings.count
            if searchController.active && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
                return filteredBuildings.count
            }
            return buildings.count
        }

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            /*
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)

            let row = indexPath.row
            cell.textLabel?.text = buildings[row].0

            return cell
            */
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
            let tuple: (String, String)
            if searchController.active && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
                tuple = filteredBuildings[indexPath.row]
            } else {
                tuple = buildings[indexPath.row]
            }
            cell.textLabel?.text = tuple.0

            return cell
        }

        // MARK:  UITableViewDelegate Methods
        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
            //tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

            let row = indexPath.row
            self.goToIndex = indexPath.row

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("MainToLocation", sender: self)
            //print(buildings[row].0)
        }

        override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

            if segue.identifier == "MainToLocation" {
                let locationViewController = (segue.destinationViewController as! LocationViewController)
                locationViewController.building = self.buildings[self.goToIndex!]
            }

        }







    extension ViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating {
        func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
            filterContentForSearchText(searchController.searchBar.text!)
        }
    }
```

Comment: My temporary solution is just checking if the viewTable is nil...

Comment: You are saying you click on a cell, prepareForSegue gets called, then you get an error in this view controllers viewDidLoad? Then you must be loading this view controller in your segue and not the view controller you think you are. If thats not the case then the description of the problem isn't clear.

Comment: since you're accessing UI elements in the viewDidLoad, it's possible they haven't been created yet. Try accessing it in the viewWillAppear or the viewDidAppear methods so you know the elements have actually been created.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this..

```
let destinationVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewController") as! NextViewController


        var alreadyPushed = false

        if let vc = self.navigationController?.viewControllers {
            for viewController in vc {
                if let viewController = viewController as? NextViewController {
                    self.navigationController?.popToViewController(viewController, animated: true)
                    print("Push your controller")
                    alreadyPushed = true
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        if alreadyPushed == false {
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVC, animated: true)
        }
```